# Firebase rules regex troubles

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, coordinates, firebase-security

```
^([-+]?)([\d]{1,2})(((\.)(\d+)(,)))(([-+]?)([\d]{1,3})((\.)(\d+))?)$
```

I am trying to use this regex above to be able to confirm that the data is a valid coordinate. I am having trouble getting this to work with Firebase rules. When i run the regex in an online regex tester, it works okay, but Firebase rules doesn't seem to accept it.

Here is my firebase rule:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^([-+]?)([\d]{1,2})(((\.)(\d+)(,)))(([-+]?)([\d]{1,3})((\.)(\d+))?)$/)"
```

Is there anyway to get this working?

Comment: Post complete code for understanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to double the escaping backslashes, but honestly, your expression contains too many redundant grouping constructs.

Use

```
.matches(/^[-+]?\\d{1,2}\\.\\d+,[-+]?\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d+)?$/)
```

or avoid the backslashes altogether:

```
.matches(/^[-+]?[0-9]{1,2}[.][0-9]+,[-+]?[0-9]{1,3}([.][0-9]+)?$/)
```

The regex will match strings [like in this online demo](https://regex101.com/r/trYekD/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string (in [Firebase regex](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex), it is an anchor when used at the start of the pattern only)
- `[-+]?` - 1 or 0 `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `[.]` - a dot
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `,` - a comma
- `[-+]?` - 1 or 0 `+` or `-`
- `[0-9]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `([.][0-9]+)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of `.` and 1+ digits (note that non-capturing groups are not supported)
- `$` - end of string anchor (only when at the pattern end, `$` matches the end of string in Firebase regex).

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. It works great!